# How to restart server without rebooting system

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Local server
PostgreSQL\9.6
PgAdmin 4 v3.2

A least once an hour pgadmin gives me an out of memory error followed by "Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.". The only way I know to recover is to reboot my system.
I know I may have other issues, like why am I running out of memory and why am I losing the connection but for right now I just want to know if there another way of restarting the server afresh without rebooting? 
If so, please explain in simple newbie terms :)

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Are you sure ou need to restart the database and not Pgadmin? (The commands would be the same just the servicename is different). And to also state the obvious such out of memories should not be normal for a database server, you sure the config matches the environment (free ram).

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS server, you can use these below commands:

PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
/bin/systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service
```

PostgreSQL 10.x

```
/bin/systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
```

PostgreSQL 11.x

```
/bin/systemctl restart postgresql-11.service
```

Answer (score 1):

> PgAdmin 4 v3.2 ...

Does that version still use the QT "wrapper" to display the application?

If so, upgrade! 
v3 leaked memory like a *sieve* on my machine, slowed itself to an absolute crawl and eventually died, just as you describe.

Newer versions open the application in your browser of choice, and they [seem to] handle memory management far better.  I haven't had a single OutOfMemory error since I upgraded to pgAdmin 4 v4.*.

Answer (score 0):

login as root and run this command

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

This will Restart your postgresql Server without rebooting the system

Answer (score -1):

login as root and run this command

```
service postgresql restart
```